# Accepted way to let user "reset" apps settings (NSUserDefaults)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, appsettings

I'd like to allow users to reset the Defaults in the iPhone's **Settings** for my app. I don't seem to be able to find any examples in apps that I've seen. Basically you'd go to Settings and find the settings for your app. At the bottom of the list there'd be some kind of option to *Reset* or *Defaults* or whatever. I'm just not sure how to handle that as I'm not aware of a plain old *Round Rect Button* we can use in Settings?!?

Best I can come up with is setting a *Switch* that says 'Reset' and the user can slide between YES and NO. Then when my app launches it looks to see if it's 'yes' then wipes the NSUserDefaults. Problem with this, as far as i can tell, is that there's no feedback when user swipes to YES. All the old settings will remain in the settings app until user launches my app and it can then do its business.

And, no, I don't want to do this from w/in the app itself - if at all possible.

Any ideas? Am I butchering the HIG?

Comment: I would very much like to know this too. If you install the Nike+ app, they have a button named "Reset Calibration" - but I'm guessing they have special powers being Nike and all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the reset setting labeled something like "at next launch, reset all to defaults" or the like. That is after all, what will happen and I think most user will understand.

Answer (score 2):

You'll not need to worry how you put it in Settings because probably only 1% of your users will ever notice you even have a settings entry.  It's nice you are trying to rely on Settings but in practice people just don't use it compared to in-app settings.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a nice idea, but I don't think this will be possible from within the Settings app, except your idea about using a switch.

Maybe file an enhancement request and ask them to make it possible to add a button to reset the settings. I personally think this kind of functionality would be nice to have.